# How to use `define to define structure like mem0, mem1?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to use `` `define `` to reduce the number of lines when coding with SystemVerilog. I can use it as below:

```
`define a(num) tb.a.b.c.d.mem[num];
```

But, I want to use as below:

```
`define a(num) tb.a.b.c.d.memnum;
```

The result should be as below:

```
`a(0) ===> tb.a.b.c.d.mem0;
`a(1) ===> tb.a.b.c.d.mem1;
`a(2) ===> tb.a.b.c.d.mem2;
```

I don't know how to generate as above.  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate tokens in macros where there isn't a normal delimiter (things like spaces, `.`, parens, etc) as in your case, you can use the double tick to explicitly separate tokens in the macro:

```
`define a(num) tb.a.b.c.d.mem``num
```